# Expose port of a specific container to external IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm deploying a helm chart that consists of a service with three replica containers.   I've been following [these directions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) for exposing a service to an external IP address.

How do I expose a port per container or per pod?  I explicitly do not want to expose a load balancer that maps that port onto some (but any) pod in the service.  The service in question is part of a stateful set, and to clients on the outside it matters which of the three are being contacted, so I can't abstract that away behind a load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new service for every pod in you stateful set. To distinguish pods you need to label them with their names like described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44103#issuecomment-326851272)
When you have separate services you can use them individually in ingress.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding the official Kubernetes documentation about creating a service:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

A Service in Kubernetes is a REST object, similar to a Pod. Like all of the REST objects, a Service definition can be POSTed to the apiserver to create a new instance. For example, suppose you have a set of Pods that each expose port 9376 and carry a label "app=MyApp".

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
```

This specification will create a new Service object named “my-service” which targets TCP port 9376 on any Pod with the "app=MyApp" label. This Service will also be assigned an IP address (sometimes called the “cluster IP”), which is used by the service proxies (see below). The Service’s selector will be evaluated continuously and the results will be POSTed to an Endpoints object also named “my-service”.

Note that a Service can map an incoming port to any targetPort. By default the targetPort will be set to the same value as the port field. Perhaps more interesting is that targetPort can be a string, referring to the name of a port in the backend Pods. The actual port number assigned to that name can be different in each backend Pod. This offers a lot of flexibility for deploying and evolving your Services. For example, you can change the port number that pods expose in the next version of your backend software, without breaking clients.

Kubernetes Services support TCP and UDP for protocols. The default is TCP.